# chrome extension to read html code of active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been searching on this topic on this site, but couldn't really find a solution to try to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I'm working on a chrome extension that by clicking a button will put in a variable the source of a webpage that I have open in the active tab, but whenever I try to perform this instead I get the html content of popup.html

My **manifest.json** file is like the following:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Project Daphne",
 "description": "Test Extension",
 "version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
 "activeTab",
"<all_urls>",
"cookies",
"tabs",
"http://*/",
"https://*/"
]
```

My **popup.html** file is instead like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project Daphne</title>
<script src="popup2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Daphne</h1>
<button id="checkPage">Use this profile!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My **popup2.js** file is like the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
var pagesource = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
d = document;
var f = d.createElement('form');
var i = d.createElement('input');
i.name = 'url';
i.value = pagesource; //modified with new --- debugger
f.appendChild(i);
d.body.appendChild(f);
    });
  }, false);
}, false);
```

I am having issues with: var pagesource = document.documentElement.outerHTML;

What I wish it would do is to retreive the HTML code of the active tab, but instead it gives me the HTML code of popup.html

Can anyone please assist me with this?

Thanks in advance for all your help and for your patience with me :)

Comment: You have to run the `document.documentElement.outerHTML` snippet in a content script via [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: I'm sorry man, I'm  totally lost with this. Would you be able to help me with an actual code example to try? I'm still learning Java.